# Why doesn't eval() work in web compilers?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, eval

While I tried to submit my code which contains eval() function, all of the web compilers like those in [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com), [programmr.com](http://programmr.com), [coursera.org](http://coursera.org) autotester, etc., returned a name error. What is the reason for not implementing this function on web compilers?

Comment: Interesting question .. as those *allow evaluation of user-input anyway*. It seems like `eval` could then be secured as much (or as little) as the other code evaluation.

Comment: It appears to be a *limitation* of said engines. `eval` works as expected on [ideone](http://ideone.com/JZx4XH). I suspect that those other tools simple lack the sound approach to implement `eval` and thus prohibit it (I've spoken harshly about the design in another comment). I see *no additional inherent danger* as, in both cases, the code to execute comes from a (remote) user.

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps they are just trying to discourage the use of `eval` :D

Answer (score 4):

An `eval` function can certainly be abused and is a security risk.

Comment: How so? The online compilers *already* allow evaluation of user input.

Comment: I would imagine that it makes code harder to filter, which allows the user to directly execute code that would normally be removed from the submitted script by rules on the server.

Comment: [`eval` really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: @StephanHeijl Then they are broken approaches to begin with :> I guess some approach without a good base could "filter" such a function in an attempt to be "safer", but I hold that they are fundamentally flawed if that's their tactic.

Comment: @unutbu If the online engines allow *user input* anyway, what difference does it make if it is in an `eval` or not?

Comment: @user2246674 Whether or not the approach is broken is irrelevant. This seems to be the most reasonable answer to the question. If the asker is intent on using the `eval` function, ideone is the solution to the issue.

Comment: @StephanHeijl I do not see what *additional* security risk is created. Presumably if arbitrary code can be executed, why does it matter if it is in an `eval`? The implementations support (or lack thereof) is orthogonal to the fundamental security issues of *any* user supplied code that is evaluated.

Comment: @StephanHeijl I am argue that this answer can be written as: "*Any* evaluation of user supplied code can certainly be abused and is a security risk." As such it does not make one method (`eval`) more dangerous than the other, excluding limitations of such engines.

Comment: I just found that [repl](http://repl.it) allows the use of eval() but there was no harm when I tried those scripts in the [blog](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) said by [ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu), in it. It would be great if anyone could explain its internal function.

Answer (score 1):

Code execution can be limited on multiple levels. The most powerful tool to limit the functionality of code is AST inspection and AST modification. Python code is parsed, tokenized, transformed into an abstract syntax tree and finally the abstract syntax tree is validated and modified.

Eval and exec can be abused to sneak code around AST inspection. Because the feature is not needed for online examples it's simply omitted.

Comment: A plausible explanation of why certain [white-list?] implementations may reject the construct. (Although it seems as though the same rules could be applied for the code supplied to eval/exec .. it might be "not worth our time" to implement such hooks/support.)

Comment: [Tiran](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2723435/tiran), Can you give some sources to get information about the parsing, tokenizing, syntax free transformation and AST inspection?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at this:

### EDIT

I don't like admitting I'm wrong but in this case I think I have to.

I'll point out that it's still true that you're executing use code either way, so you need to actually secure the interpreter. I still believe that "there is no point whatsoever trying to blacklist, or even whitelist, allowed actions if those actions exist within the interpreter" and thus blocking `exec` and `eval` aids only minor benefit.

Here's the key point:

The maker of that Python Tutor executed code handed to them from the outside. Despite blocking many things, including `exec`, because they allowed executing of foreign code there is an exploit I have found. Currently I've only imported a blocked module, but reading the source this also allows me to do unlimited IO.

**Further Edit**: I've contacted the owner of Python Tutor and he's said he's aware of such, supposedly protections exist at a lower level, too. So it's not an exploit, but that's primarily because there are protections at "a lower level". That's how you're meant to guard against attacks, not blacklists.

***Further,*** Further Edit: I've brought down Python Tutor, although the site seems to be up again (not functional, just up), 'cause I was seeing whether I could read/write anything with this exploit of mine (at the request of Philip Guo, the owner). It seems I can at least break the site :/. Sorry, 'twas an accident. It does prove that running untrusted code is dangerous, though, which is what I've been saying all along.

However, the question asks about *intention*, not about whether blocking `exec` actually makes a difference.

Reading http://pgbovine.net/projects/pubs/guo-sigcse-preprint_2012-11-13.pdf, namely

> Since the backend is running untrusted Python code from the web, it implements sandboxing to prevent the execution of dangerous constructs such as `eval`, `exec`, file I/O and most module imports (except for a customisable whitelist of modules such as `math`).

I won't admit that I'm wrong about how you *should* treat `exec` and `eval`, but I was wrong about what the site's *owner* thought you should do (although admittedly he realises that you *also* have to sandbox).

---

### What I previously wrote:

**Firstly, it is almost definitely nothing to do with safety.** Safety by obscurity never works, and it's a silly thing to try. You cannot blacklist bad functions by looking for calls to the function in a dynamic language. An easy example of obscuring

```
import os; while True: os.fork()
```

would be

```
import os
while True:
    os.__dict__["fork"]()
```

so there's no protection. I'll say it again: there is **no point *whatsoever* trying to blacklist, or even whitelist, allowed actions if those actions exist within the interpreter**. This means that **anything** `eval` can reach can be reached **without** `eval`, so blocking `eval` gives you **no** security.

---

I reckon the real reason is that these aren't typical Python compiler-interpreters. Much of what the code is doing is pushed onto Javascript or some other awkward platform.

If you ever deeply inspect code, you'll realise that at compile-to-bytecode-time some stuff gets hard coded, such as name bindings. When running things like "eval" you cannot just run the code inline, you have to compile and dynamically extract things from a scope. Supporting such dynamism in a target language is a challenging task, and the writers probably just didn't think that it was worth doing.

This is especially true if the code is compiled in the cloud and executed locally: `eval` would therefore have to take a round-trip to the server in order to work! This isn't an advised course of action.

That's my guess, although I don't know how this stuff is actually implemented.

Comment: You are wrong. There are plenty of ways to block harmful function. For example a limited interpreter can block all function that aren't white listed. A sandboxed interpreter can use AST inspection to limit the scope and functionality. You can even block sys calls on the operating system level with e.g. SECCOMP.

Comment: Either it also blocks the danger when done through `eval`, in which case there's no reason to block `eval`, or it's ineffective. Most of what you said works for both generic code and `eval`, although I'm not sure what you mean by "block functions". That's the point I was making, I've clarified in the post.

Comment: Of course you can fix `eval`. But it's more work and an additional security risk. Why take the risk when the function is not needed for an online course?

Comment: See my update as a response to that question. The point is that if you're executing arbitrary code there's **nothing** you can do with `exec` or `eval` that you can't do without, period. Therefore blocking `exec` or `eval` gives **no** security benefit.